# optimistic locking in spring jpa is not updating the value if the version was more than 0

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, optimistic-locking

i used optimistic lock by only write @version in entity ..
and it work when version is 0 , so if i updated the entity and the version was 0 it work and do the update and make the version 1 automatically , but once the version is 1 , it wont accept any other update ... what can i do ..
i thought of doing it manually without @version , like compairing the entety version with its value before update if equall do update or else no ... but how to use it using @version

```
package com.hariri_stocks.models;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Version;

@Table
@Entity
public class Estates {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private long id;
    @Column
    private String place;
    @Column
    private int price;
    @Column
    private long stocks_num;
    @Column
    private boolean sold = false;
    @Version
    private long version;
    
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "estate_id",fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
    private SoldEstates sold_estate_id;

    public Estates() {
        super();
    }

    public Estates(String place, int price, long stocks_num, SoldEstates sold_estate_id) {
        super();
        this.place = place;
        this.price = price;
        this.stocks_num = stocks_num;

        this.sold_estate_id = sold_estate_id;
    }

    
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPlace() {
        return place;
    }

    public void setPlace(String place) {
        this.place = place;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public long getStocks_num() {
        return stocks_num;
    }

    public void setStocks_num(long stocks_num) {
        this.stocks_num = stocks_num;
    }




    public long getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(long version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public boolean isSold() {
        return sold;
    }

    public void setSold(boolean sold) {
        this.sold = sold;
    }

    public SoldEstates getSold_estate_id() {
        return sold_estate_id;
    }

    public void setSold_estate_id(SoldEstates sold_estate_id) {
        this.sold_estate_id = sold_estate_id;
    }

    
    
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be setting version yourself (which is probably the issue), and as it is a `long` it will revert to `0` if you are just re-createing objects. `0` != `1` and hence it wont' update.

Comment: how to not setting it my self please

Comment: Please show us the code where you are trying to update your entity.